# animation for zoom in and zoom out in android for imageview

Tags: android-animation

How do i set zoom in and zoom out when click on imageview?I want my program to react when user click on imageview must get large to some extent and can move imageview on that screen and sometime it reduce the size along when it move on touch anywhere on the screen .when click again is go resume original size what do i do?

Answer (score 15):

As far as I know there are two ways.

The first way:

Make a new folder in res called 'anim'. Than make a xml file inside, for example zoomin.xml. Afterwards put the following code inside.

```
<scale  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromXScale="1" 
  android:toXScale="5" 
  android:fromYScale="1" 
  android:toYScale="5" 
  android:pivotX="50%" 
  android:pivotY="50%" 
  android:duration="1000" 
  android:fillAfter="true">
</scale>
```

Make another one for zoom out, but with reversed values.

```
<scale  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromXScale="5" 
  android:toXScale="1" 
  android:fromYScale="5" 
  android:toYScale="1" 
  android:pivotX="50%" 
  android:pivotY="50%" 
  android:duration="1000" 
  android:fillAfter="true">
</scale>
```

You can change the values according to your needs. I think that they are self-explanatory.

And now in your java code.

```
ImageView imageView = (imageView)findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewId);

Animation zoomin = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoomin);
Animation zoomout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoomout);
imageView.setAnimation(zoomin);
imageView.setAnimation(zoomout);
```

Now you only need to keep track which is the current state. And for each state execute this lines of codes:

```
imageView.startAnimation(zoomin);
```

and

```
imageView.startAnimation(zoomout);
```

For example:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!pressed) {
                    v.startAnimation(zoomin);
                    pressed = !pressed;
                } else {
                    v.startAnimation(zoomout);
                    pressed = !pressed;
                }
            }
        });
```

The other way is described here : http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can make this by following this guide easily

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

shortly you should use third imageview which is invisible when the user touches any imageview you want, you can display it by using animation in the imageview which is invisible.